# Finding all polynomials that become zero when certain differential operators act on them

Tags: differential-equations

Consider some differential operators that do not have $x^n$ type of coefficients, i.e., only as powers of $\partial_x$, $\partial_y$ or sum of a few such terms with constant coefficients. For example, let us consider $D_1 = \partial_x \partial_y$ and $D_2 = \partial_y^2$. We then want to look for all polynomials $p(x,y)$ that $D_1 p = 0$ and $D_2 p = 0$.

In the example above, it is easy to see that the answer  is
$p = c + a_1 y + \sum_{n=1} b_n x^n$

Now my question is, given a set of $D_1, D_2, \dots$, how do we find all polynomials $p(x,y,z,\dots)$ s.t. $D_i p = 0$? What is the branch of math that treats such problems systematically?

Comment: Hi, you should look at what is called "differential algebra" and also "computer algebra" for actual implementations. Yet beware that, with more than 2 variables, these questions are highly non-trivial (e.g. Poinacré question about existence of rational first-integrals in planar polynomial vector fields).